# Как создать Listbox, который содержит TextBlock и ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

Пытаюсь собрать `Listbox`, который содержит `TextBlock` и `ComboBox`. Причем на каждой итерации данные в `ComboBox` должны быть разные.

```
<ListView Name="lbTodoList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding vopros}" />
                <ComboBox Name="combo"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          IsEditable="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=ItemsSource}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding otvet}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Для этого создал отдельный класс со следующим содержанием

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public string vopros { get; set; }
    public List<string> otvet { get; set; }
}
```

И пытаюсь наполнить все вот так

```
List<TodoItem> items = new List<TodoItem>();
items.Add(new TodoItem() { vopros = "vopros1", otvet = new List<string>() { "b1", "b2", "b3" } });
items.Add(new TodoItem() { vopros = "vopros2", otvet = new List<string>() { "a1", "a2"} });
lbTodoList.ItemsSource = items;
```

Но в конечном итоге все собирается не так, как предполагалось

[image: Как все отображается]

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Зачем в `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` пихать еще и текстблок? При биндинге он и так поймет, что ему надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если проблема в отображении, тогда надо сделать так:

```
<ListView Name="lbTodoList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding vopros}" />
                <ComboBox Name="combo" Grid.Column="1" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding otvet}">
                </ComboBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```